# How to localize currency lNuxtJS i18n

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

As you know currency format differs in Europe countries .
in Germany 1.234.567,89
in England 1.234.567.89
how can i use nuxt/i18n localization for currency .
i have this code in nuxt config

```js
i18n: {
  locales: [
    { code: 'en', iso: 'en-US', dir: 'ltr' },
    { code: 'de', iso: 'de-GER', dir: 'ltr' },
  ],
  defaultLocale: 'de',
  vueI18n: {
    numberFormats: {
      'en-US': {
        currency: {
           style: 'currency', 
            currency: 'USD',
            currencyDisplay: 'USD'
           }
      },
      'de-GER': {
        currency: {
           style: 'currency', 
            currency: 'EUR',
            currencyDisplay: 'EUR'
           }
      }
    },
    fallbackLocale: 'de',
    messages: {
      en: en.messages,
      de: de.messages,
    },
  },
},
```

and when i use

```html
<p>{{ $n(100, 'currency') }}</p>
```

but I do get this error

```
RangeError
Value EUR out of range for Intl.NumberFormat options property currencyDisplay
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like a browser issue, where did you tried this one? More info here: https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/980

Comment: just 'de-GER' has problem , in 'en-US' it works fine

Comment: `de-GER`? Is that something regular? Usually it's `2-2` letters combo no? Maybe try `de-GE` idk. Does it work with the vanilla JS `Intl.NumberFormat` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `'de-GE'` rather than `'de-GER'` fixed the issue!